# Why doesn't read conditions?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api

I did use debug and the price range doesn't read from the condition.
if (cost <= 500.00)
Also i tried 'where' instead of 'select' By the way i can use another methods.
Thanks for any help
`

```
 public T CostRange(int cost)
        {
            var price = GetByCost(cost);
            if (price != null)
            {

                if (cost <= 500.00)
                {
                 _context.Set<T>().Select(x => x.Cost <= 500).ToList();

                }
               
                if (cost > 500 || cost <= 2000)
                {
                   _context.Set<T>().Select(x => x.Cost > 500 && x.Cost <= 2000).ToList();

                }
                if (cost > 2000 || cost <= 5000)
                {
                   _context.Set<T>().Select(x => x.Cost > 2000 && x.Cost <= 5000).ToList();

                }
                if (cost > 5000 || cost <= 10000)
                { 
                    _context.Set<T>().Select(x => x.Cost > 5000 && x.Cost <= 10000).ToList();

                }
                if (cost > 10000)
                {
                   _context.Set<T>().Select(x => x.Cost > 10000).ToList();
                }
            }
          
            return price;
        }
```

`

I want to get products in price range.By the way I can reach the cost value with
'_context.Set().Find(cost); or GetByCost(cost);

Comment: `cost > 500 || cost <= 2000` - you probably mean `&&`, not `||`

Comment: All of these (` _context.Set<T>().Select(x => x.Cost <= 500).ToList();`) do nothing. They have to return a value to a variable, you're just throwing away their result.

Comment: I guess var getprice =  _context.Set<T>().Select(x => x.Cost <= 500).ToList(); @gilliduck
May you share any example??

Comment: `Select()` is the wrong LINQ operator, you want `Where()`: `.Where(x => x.Cost > 500 && x.Cost <= 2000)`. And you also need to fix the mistake mentiond by @KlausGütter.

Comment: unfortunately, it doesn't work. it doesn't read form if(cost >500)  @KlausGütter

Comment: What does "it doesn't read form" mean?

Comment: When I use debug , i see,, if(cost <= 500) return execution without reading code with definition and other conditions.